# Format dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, format

I have to log my error with datetime in some file, for that I am using following code:

```
var dLogDate = new Date();
console.log(dLogDate.toString().substring(4) + ', ' + dLogDate.toGMTString().substring(4));
```

as per above code output comes as follows which is nice but not formated as I need:

```
"Oct 10 2014 12:48:59 GMT+0530 (IST),  10 Oct 2014 07:18:59 GMT"
```

I want result s follows :

```
"10 Oct 2014 12:48:59 (IST),  10 Oct 2014 07:18:59 (GMT)"
```

see date part before ",". I need ***10 Oct*** instated of ***Oct 10***

This can be done with some function which is substring first 4 character from string and concat at 3rd position again, But I am still curious to know if there are any other simple way to do this? I don't want to use any third party library/script.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com/). It's a library for working with dates in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can use date functions to format date

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

`var monthIndex = date.getMonth();`

`var dayIndex = date.getDay();`

`var monthArray = ['January',....];`

`var dayArray = ['Sunday',...]`

`console.log(monthArray[monthIndex] + "-" + dayArray[dayIndex]);`

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding to the prototype an extension method `toISTString`

```
function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10) ? '0' + n : n;
}

Date.prototype.toISTString = function(locale) {
    var year = this.getFullYear().toString();
    var month = this.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "short" }) // ECMAScript Internationalization API, which is very new only available in Blink browsers (Chrome and Opera), IE11, and Firefox 29+.
    var day  = this.getDate().toString();
    var hrs = this.getHours().toString();
    var mins = this.getMinutes().toString();   
    var secs = this.getSeconds().toString();
    return day + " " + month + " " + year + " " + pad(hrs) + ":" + pad(mins) + ":" + secs + " (IST)";
};

dLogDate = new Date();
console.log(dLogDate.toISTString("en-us") + ', ' + dLogDate.toGMTString().substring(4));
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/jz26d9pq/)**